# What is the first place in AspNetCore 3 where I can use IServiceProvider

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper

I want to provide a static class with `AutoMapper` configuration as soon as possible at application startup. The goal is to create custom mapping extensions, which internally call `ProjectTo` and `Map` and provide necessary configuration. That way I can have consistent and clean mapping API across the project:

```cs
var articleDetails = this.dbContext
    .Articles
    .Map<ArticleDetails();
```

to achieve that I need to provide my static `MappingExtensions` class with instance of `IMapper`, where I can get the configuration from. What is a good spot to do so in order to have that static class configured before I could hit any `Map` calls? There must be some sort of hook I can latch on after `IServiceProvider` has been initialized.

Comment: You simply shouldn’t use static classes with ASP.NET Core at all. Use the NuGet package `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` to properly integrate AutoMapper with ASP.NET Core and inject `IMapper` where necessary: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Thanks, poke, for your input. I am aware of how to use IMapper, but I don't like that API. Still I have decided that I want to wrap it in extension methods and my question is where would be a good spot to hook in.

Answer (score 0):

After some further poking a probing I've decided to use `IWebHost` extension, which is where I see people putting initialization logic. `IWebHost.Services` exposes `IServiceProvider` which is exactly what I need.